# Differences between some functions in Java

Tags: java, function, methods

I am new to Java and coming from a background in Python. I am curious about the difference between using the `Math.round(VALUE)` function versus casting to an integer like `(int) VALUE`. In Python, the equivalent to casting to an integer is `int(VALUE)`, so I am struggling to understand the distinction in Java. Can someone explain this difference to me?

Comment: Calling `(int) VALUE` would cast a `float` to an `int` in Java. In Java, casting is not a function call like in Python. In Java, you just place the type you want in parenthesis before the value you want to cast. Python and Java are two very different languages. If you want to learn Java, set aside what you know about Python and read some Java tutorials to get a better understanding. The `Math.round` static method (or function as you may) has a lot more overhead than a simple typecast. Also, casting to an `int` truncates the decimal, it does not round it. So both may have different output.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Oh, thanks for the info. So, is casting values the only time you'd do something like `(int) VALUE`?

Comment: Yes, casting a value does not require a function call, but you could have a method that internally casts a value and returns a new one.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Alright, thanks so much for the clarification on this!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to "cast".

1. If you are parsing a string in Python, you would call `int(str)`, but in Java you would have to use the boxed type's (`Integer.class`) static parsing method i.e `Integer.parseInt(str)`

   ```py
   # Python
   str_val = '42'
   int_val = int(str_val) # 42
   print(type(str_val))   # <class 'str'>
   print(type(int_val))   # <class 'int'>
   ```

   ```java
   /* Java */
   String strVal = "42";
   int intVal = Integer.parseInt(strVal); // 42
   ```
2. If you are converting a floating-point in Python, you would call `int(floating_value)`, but in Java you would simply place the desired type i.e. `(int)` before the value i.e. `(int) floatingValue`.

   ```py
   # Python
   floating_value = 3.14
   int_val = int(floating_value) # 3
   print(type(floating_value))   # <class 'float'>
   print(type(int_val))          # <class 'int'>
   ```

   ```java
   /* Java */
   float floatingVal = 3.14;
   int intVal = (int) floatingVal; // 3
   ```

Python treats typecasting and parsing very similarly.

Answer (score 1):

To preface, you mention the following.

> *"... In Python, the equivalent to casting to an integer is `int(VALUE)` ..."*

The *[Math#round](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#round(double))* function may not be the procedure you're looking for.

In Java, you can cast a *[String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)* value to an *[int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)* value using the *[Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))* method.

```java
int value = Integer.parseInt("123");
```

> *"... I am curious about the difference between using the `Math.round(VALUE)` function versus casting to an integer like `(int) VALUE` ..."*

If you are speaking in terms of a rounding mode, then the *Math#round* method is going to round towards positive infinity.

Consider the following demonstration.

```java
double[] values = { 5.5, 2.5, 1.6, 1.1, 1.0, -1.0, -1.1, -1.6, -2.5, -5.5 };
for (double value : values)
    System.out.printf("%4.1f to %2d%n", value, Math.round(value));
```

```
 5.5 to  6
 2.5 to  3
 1.6 to  2
 1.1 to  1
 1.0 to  1
-1.0 to -1
-1.1 to -1
-1.6 to -2
-2.5 to -2
-5.5 to -5
```

Whereas, a cast to an *int* is going to simply truncate the fractional value.
No rounding will occur.

```java
double[] values = { 5.5, 2.5, 1.6, 1.1, 1.0, -1.0, -1.1, -1.6, -2.5, -5.5 };
for (double value : values)
    System.out.printf("%4.1f to %2d%n", value, (int) value);
```

```
 5.5 to  5
 2.5 to  2
 1.6 to  1
 1.1 to  1
 1.0 to  1
-1.0 to -1
-1.1 to -1
-1.6 to -1
-2.5 to -2
-5.5 to -5
```